# Aligning contents of a div right while keeping text direction in input fields going ltr

Tags: css, html, alignment, right-to-left

I am trying to aligning contents of a div to right edge, but I'm getting 'direction: rtl' effect (right to left), without specifying the width of the div? while keeping text direction in input fields going ltr (left to right).  Is it possible?

Applying direction: right to div almost acheives effect, except text fields inputs also become rtl.  (I guess align: right also works, but is depreciated)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div style="direction: rtl;">
    Text is right-aligned
    <input type="text" value="Some value" style="direction: ltr;" />
</div>
```

Comment: I know that but I have images and input field also.

Comment: Check the updated answer. You may use *css* to apply styles to all elements.

Comment: nice, but i think i tried this already and the outer rtl overrides the inner ltr. strange but true, i think.

Comment: okay, text-align right seems to work, even for input fields had read that it wouldnt work. sorry